# EPSON thermal printer leaves too much margin on printing by Google Cloud Print

Tags: android, thermal-printer, google-cloud-print

I am using Google Cloud Print api to print receipts in EPSON TM T82II.I have specified print job ticket for 3 copies with no margin.But its not reflecting in my printouts.

```
{
    "version":"1.0",
    "print":{
        "vendor_ticket_item":[],
        "color":{
            "type":"STANDARD_MONOCHROME"
        },
        "margins":{
            "top_microns":0,
            "right_microns":0,
            "bottom_microns":0,
            "left_microns":0
        },
        "fit_to_page":{
            "type":1
        },
        "copies":{
            "copies":3
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer - but a query does the EPSON TM T82II print automatically from Google Cloud Print without the need to be connected to a computer?

Comment: Yeah..it does.Use Google Cloud Print api